# Can Gremlin P.eq accept a Vertex?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to apply the [Element Existence recipe](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.9/recipes/#element-existence) to insert only one edge that's considered "live" (not "expired"):

```
def to = __.V(member).hasLabel('Member')

gts.V(group).hasLabel('Group')
  .coalesce(
    __.outE('Includes').hasNot('ttl.end').where(__.inV().is(P.eq(to))),
    __.addE('Includes').to(to).property('ttl.start', timestamp)
  )
  .next()
```

My expectation is that the coalesce will select an existing edge that has no `ttl.end` property and is incident onto the same `to` vertex, or else insert a new edge. However, a new edge is always inserted anyway. I interpret this as indicating that the first subtraversal isn't matching the existing live edge, but I'm not figuring out why. Does the predicate `P.eq` work for a `Traversal<?, Vertex>` argument? If not, what's the correct way to say "where the edge ends on vertex `to`"?

Profile (I note the `IsStep` has no traversers, which I interpret to mean it did not match):

```
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[08f8c62d-5429-40e6-84b7...                     1           1           0.135    10.93
CoalesceStep([[VertexStep(OUT,[Includes],edge),...                     1           1           0.781    63.17
  VertexStep(OUT,[Includes],edge)                                      2           2           0.025
  NotStep([PropertiesStep([ttl.end],value), Pro...                     1           1           0.127
    PropertiesStep([ttl.end],value)                                                            0.033
  TraversalFilterStep([EdgeVertexStep(IN), Prof...                                             0.144
    EdgeVertexStep(IN)                                                 1           1           0.014
    IsStep(eq([TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[d9b69296...                                             0.018
  AddEdgeStep({ttl.start=[Thu Jan 28 21:27:52 C...                     1           1           0.220
    TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[d9b69296-333e-4e54-...                     1           1           0.120
```

Answer (score 0):

Either should work:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> v = g.V(1).next()
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().bothE().where(outV().is(v))
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.V().bothE().where(outV().is(eq(v)))
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
```

Note that your code example doesn't show you providing a `Vertex` to `is()` or `eq()`. The  following:

```
def to = __.V(member).hasLabel('Member')
```

never gets the `Vertex` because the [traversal is not iterated](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration). Therefore `to` is just a `Traversal` and that certainly won't provide any matches in your `where()`.

Comment: Okay, I _think_ I see where this is coming from, but this solution does not work in the constraint of a one-shot traversal, and I suspect won't work on most providers generally; it requires first retrieving `V(1)` and then using it as an Object value (fine in TinkerGraph, but not Neptune). What's the most suitable way to say "where inV is the same vertex" in a single traversal?

Comment: most (all?) providers will support this. i wasn't aware that Neptune couldn't take a `Vertex`. You can certainly retrieve one from Neptune but if you can't send one back then just use the id, no? `g.V().bothE().where(outV().hasId(v.id())`

Comment: It's possible I'm mistaken about that, but in either case it's not a single-traversal transaction. I may be able to make the `.id()` form work.

Comment: In my actual code the `coalesce` is inside a method with the `to` passed as a parameter (i.e., find an existing edge if present, add otherwise), and using `to.id()` mutates the subtraversal, causing it to fail when a traversal to vertex is expected. (The ability to post-facto morph a generics-compliant `Traversal<A, Vertex>` to an `Traversal<A, Object>` is unexpected.) I've opened 2515 regarding this; that might unfortunately be a change requiring 3.5.